# is there a formula to "invert" the binomial distribution - for simulation purposes

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, simulation

My apologies if this should be in one of the programming sites rather than the mathematics one... I decided it was theoretical enough to post here.  Feel free to move if someone with authority disagrees strongly.   ;-)

So the layman's version of the question I'm asking is: I want to simulate flipping a coin until I get 75 'heads'.  How many times did I flip the coin?  In reality I'm trying to monte-carlo an algorithm that statistically counts events over a long period of time with very large (> 10^15) numbers of events.

The brute force approach here is obvious:  I just write some code that loops over flipping a coin until I get my 75th head, then return the number of times I flipped it.  But this is O(n) and gets **really** expensive/slow for large numbers of flips.

I can use the probability mass function and/or the cumulative distribution of binomial events to answer related questions, but I can't seem to find something that will "invert" this function (if that's even the right term?) and give me a single statistical answer to the direction I'm trying to do it ... obviously each iteration of this will result in a different number of flips, but the results of a lot of these trials will look binomial.

Comment: What about using the central limit theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sampling the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution). Inverse transform sampling of that distribution requires numerically solving an equation involving the beta function.

Comment: “Negative” rather than “inverse” is exactly what I needed. Thanks.  With that O(1) function I can sample any point along that distribution, then binary search for the number of failures and do that in O(log(n)) rather than having to monte-Carlo the whole thing at O(n).  Thanks :-)